# Extending 2-adic valuation to real numbers

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

When proving Monsky's theorem, one of the steps, which, from what I have so far seen, no proof can avoid, is extending the 2-adic valuation to all real numbers, so that it still satisfies $|xy|_2=|x|_2|y|_2$ and $|x+y|_2\leq\max\{|x|_2,|y|_2\}$. However, no proof of Monsky's theorem which I have seen explained why this extension exists. One of the proofs has mentioned that the proof of existence requires axiom of choice. This made me think that standard argument using Zorn's lemma would do the trick, but I have realized that giving arbitrary value to an irrational will not always lead to consistent valuation (e.g. we can't set $|\sqrt{2}|_2=1$, as this would lead to $|2|_2=|\sqrt{2}\cdot\sqrt{2}|_2=|\sqrt{2}|_2^2=1\neq\frac{1}{2}=|2|_2$).

> How does one prove existence of an extension of $|\cdot|_2$ as specified above?

Comment: Looks to me, with my untrained eyes (and they are not well-trained in judging the complexity of these sort of statements), that for a fixed $n$, the statement is $\Pi^1_2$, therefore absolute between $L$ and $V$. So for each odd $n$ the statement is provable without choice, therefore it is provable without choice. Why is this tagged as [axiom-of-choice] and not [p-adic-number-theory] for example?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have added [p-adic-number-theory] tag. As for axiom of choice - as I have mentioned in the body of my question, I heard that the (standard) proof of Monsky actually does use choice. If that's avoidable - great enough, if not - let it be.

Comment: Do you *know* the standard proof? It's easy to ask "Hey, I heard about this theorem, and it seems to me that it is using the axiom of choice, can it be done without it?", but if you don't know the usual proof, then perhaps it is worth learning *that* part first. The [axiom-of-choice] tag is for questions specifically about the role of the axiom in proofs, and what can happen in its absence. Since you don't know the usual proof, it seems strange that you'd ask for the role of choice in that proof.

Comment: @AsafKaragila No, I don't know a standard proof using choice (indeed, my question asks for details the part of proof which uses choice). I guess that I indeed should put away the part of the question which asks about necessity of choice, and maybe make it into another question later on.

Comment: can't $\Bbb R$ (even $\Bbb C$) be embedded as a subfield of $\overline{\Bbb Q_2}$ ?

Comment: @mercio, $C$ is in fact isomorphic to the algebraic closure of $Q_2$.

Comment: It seems that this question is essentially answered [on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/q/107043). Or at least, the part about Monsky's theorem is addressed there. The extension of the 2-adic valuation to the reals (or even the complex numbers) is discussed in most textbooks on $p$-adic numbers. It does require choice, but that is overkill for Monsky's theorem.

Answer (score 5):

> How does one prove the existence of an extension of $|\cdot|_2$ as specified above?

Any p-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$. The construction is as follows: since there exists a field isomorphism $T:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}_p$ that extends the identity map in $\mathbb{Q}$, you can define the valuation $|\cdot|_*:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{R}$ by $|x|_*=|T(x)|_p$. It is not hard to see that $|x+y|_*\leq\max\{|x|_*,|y|_*\}$ for all $x,y\in\mathbb{C}$. Then, the restriction of $|\cdot|_*$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a valuation on $\mathbb{R}$ that extends the $p$-adic valuation of $\mathbb{Q}$. Of course, this construction cannot be done explicitly since there is not an explicit formula for $T$. We only know about its existence. A proof of the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}_p$ are isomorphic can be found on page 83 of the book: Non-Archimedean Functional Analysis - [A.C.M. van Rooij] - 1978.

More generally, it has been proven (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2756388/113061)) that any two algebraically closed fields of the same characteristic and cardinality are isomorphic.

Answer (score 3):

$\Large A $fter digging up Lang and related [sources](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/8410FULL.pdf), which says the 2-adic valuation on $\mathbb{Q}$ can be extended to $\mathbb{R}$.

> Let $(K, | \cdot|)$ be an ordered field and $L/K$ be an extension.  If either of the following holds, then there is a norm on $L$ extending $|\cdot|$.

- $L/K$ is Algebraic
- $(K, |\cdot|)$ is non-Archimedian

Thus $(\mathbb{R}, |\cdot|_2)$ is **very** different from the familiar Euclidean $(\mathbb{R}, ||\cdot||)$.  E.g. $\sqrt{2}$ can no longer be approximated as the limit of rational numbers; it's only definition is as the positive solution of $x^2 = 2$.  My guess is that you simply adjoin elements inductively.   Whenever you find an element in $\mathbb{R}$ not in your extension.

This may be an important insight into Monsky's problem that the natural topology on $[0,1]^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ for this problem.  Using the 2-adic norm, Monsky paritions the unit square into 3 subsets:

- $A = \{ (x,y): ||x|| < 1 \text{ and } ||y|| < 1\;\;\;\;\,\}$
- $B = \{ (x,y): ||x|| > 1 \text{ and } ||x|| > ||y||\}$
- $C = \{ (x,y): ||y|| > 1 \text{ and } ||y|| > ||x||\}$

In Euclidean norm, these subsets (representing vertices of triangles) are dense in the unit square

Think about it -- it's very easy to draw a partition of a square into triangles.  How can it be that *none* of them have equal area? You could try to draw an arrangement of triangles with some parameters; then they have some relationship which you can solve for.  Monsky shows even with those equations you can find no solution.

---

From Comments:

> I don't see what's the problem with defining R as a completion of Q under archimedean metric, and afterwards asking for **an** extension of non-archimedean metric to this completion. Note that we are not asking R to be complete w.r.t. to this extended metric.

You can take 2-adic completion of any extension $K/\mathbb{Q}$ but this extension may not be unique. To ensure the existence of a completion over $\mathbb{R}$, the axiom of choice may be required.

As your example suggests, clearly the roots of 2 need special attention possibly $|\sqrt[n]{2}|_2 = \frac{1}{2^{1/n}}$ but there are weirder ones as well:

$$ 2 = (3 +  \sqrt{7})(3 - \sqrt{7}) \text{ so that }   |3 +  \sqrt{7}|_2 |3 - \sqrt{7}|_2 = \tfrac{1}{2}$$

Probably they are both $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$.  So this valuation has to be extended real algebraic integers $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \mathbb{R}$.

[Monsky's paper](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/Monsky70.pdf) says you need only extend $\mathbb{Q}$ by the coordinates of the $m$ vertices.  This is a **finite** extension, although you won't know which ones they are *a priori*.

---

We should also note that even dissections **are** possible, but that's not the issue you are worried about.

[image]

Wikipedia has discussions on some [equidissection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equidissection) problems and the [Dehn Invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_third_problem) related to Hilbert's 3rd problem.

Comment: Actually, with 2-adic, we don't have $2^n\rightarrow\infty$ - indeed, we have $2^n\rightarrow 0$, because $|2^n-0|_2=\frac{1}{2^n}$ which can be smaller than any $\varepsilon$ if $n$ are large enough.

Comment: Also, I highly doubt that $\sum\frac{1}{4^n}$ is convergent. In 2-adic metric, sequence of partial sums is not even Cauchy, as the difference of consecutive terms is $\frac{1}{4^n}$, and this sequence doesn't tend to 0, because taking $\varepsilon=1$ we will never have $|\frac{1}{4^n}-0|_2<1$.

Comment: The extension only has to satisfy 3 properties, and I can't see any reason, intuitive or formal, which would make existence of this extension implausible or impossible. We can in exactly the same way ask question about extension of 2-adic metric to any field containing Q. Also remember that there is more than one definition of R, so we can easily ask the same question without ever mentioning Cauchy sequences and alike.

Comment: To comment on one more thing from your answer - I don't see what's the problem with defining R as a completion of Q under archimedean metric, and afterwards asking for extension of non-archimedean metric to this completion. Note that we are not asking R to be complete w.r.t. to this extended metric.

Comment: @Wojowu I now agree. You can define 2-adic norms over any extension over $\mathbb{Q}$.  This includes algebraic extensions like $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})_2$ or  $[\mathbb{Q}[x]/(x^3 - x - 1)]_2$ and transcendental extensions like $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$.  Then $\mathbb{R}$ contains all of these.    This is even beigger than the **algebraic closure** $\overline{\mathbb{Q}} \cap \mathbb{R}$ containing all real algebraic extensions.

Comment: @Wojowu I think $\sum\frac{1}{4^n}\to \frac{4^n-1}{3\times4^n}=\frac{1}{3}$; does that look right?

Comment: @RobertFrost Not in $2$-adic metric, since $|\frac{1}{4}|_2>1$.

Comment: @Wojowu ah ok so $\frac{1}{3}$ is fine but $\frac{-1}{3\times4^n}$ diverges... and therefore is undefined?  So I have proven it diverges!

Comment: @RobertFrost Pretty much.

Comment: About the norms of $3+\sqrt7$ and $3-\sqrt7$: they must both be equal to $1/\sqrt2$. First, $|3\pm\sqrt7|>1/2$, since otherwise $1/2=|3+\sqrt7||3-\sqrt7|\leq1/4$. Then $|3-\sqrt7|>1/2=1/2\cdot 1=|2\sqrt7|$ implies $|3+\sqrt7|=|(3-\sqrt7)+2\sqrt7|=|3-\sqrt7|$.

Comment: A more instructive example is $8=(5+\sqrt{17})(5-\sqrt{17})$ in which one of the factors must have absolute value $1/2$, the other $1/4$, and you can choose either. Compare end of https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3260194/96384. This is only the quadratic case; for higher degree extensions, one has many more choices. I stand by what I wrote in https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2563837/96384: The problem is not that one cannot extend a $p$-adic value to $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$; the problem is that one has far too infinitely many choices to do that, hence it's impossible to do it explicitly.