# Extending absolute value to p-adic number

Tags: p-adic-number-theory, valuation-theory

[Extending 2-adic valuation to real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1348581/extending-2-adic-valuation-to-real-numbers)
So i know $\mathbb{R}$ has $p$-adic valuation

But could we have absolute value $|\cdot|$ to $p$-adic number?

Comment: If this is your question then yes $\Bbb{C}$ contains all the transcendental extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$ with a not too large cardinality, in particular it contains a copy of $\Bbb{Q}_p$, but the embedding $\Bbb{Q_p\to C}$ is an abstract nonsense requiring the axiom of choice. Conversely the $|.|_p$ completion of $\overline{\Bbb{Q}}_p$ contains a copy of $\Bbb{C}$.

Comment: Oh.. absolute value mean usual real absolute value sorry my question is $\mathbb{Q}$ has very usual absolute value and it is still work to $\Bbb{Q_p}$

Comment: The embedding defines the absolute value... For example $|f(x)|_\infty = |f(\pi)|$ is an absolute value on $\Bbb{Q}(x)$